# Pattern match : print the strings in next line of Pattern in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Here is my pattern of string , 'ACTION' is my pattern. Expression should return 3 parameters present in next line of pattern:

Here is the pattern :

```
ACTION    QUANTITY  USOC      DESCRIPTION                                      
Impact    1         E8PAM     /FIN QC
```

Expression should return `$1 = Impact , $2= 1, $3= USOC , $4=/FIN QC`

Here is my trial :

```
 if ($line =~/ACTION(.*?)(\s+?)$/) {      
    print $array[$i];
    }
```

This is giving output like :

```
Impact    1         E8PAM     /FIN QC
```

Comment: `$3= USOC` or `$3=E8PAM`?

Comment: Get next line after `ACTION` and split on whitespaces.

Comment: I have tried to get the separate parameters, but I am getting  result as         Impact    1         E8PAM     /FIN QC , But I want it in separate parameter results.. I have edited my trial code in question. Please anyone can give me suggestion

Comment: Where does `@array` come from?

Comment: You say "Expression should return 3 parameters present in next line of pattern" but then, later, you say "Expression should return `$1 = Impact , $2= 1, $3= USOC , $4=/FIN QC`", which is four values. You're not being very clear about what you want.

Comment: Perhaps use capturing groups to get `$1` etc http://rextester.com/XFEFYQ87085

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Using `split()` would seem to be far simpler.

Comment: @DaveCross Yes it is, the OP used a regex in the question so this is just a suggestion of how you might do it using capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer this question :

```
          if ($line =~ /ACTION(.*?)(\s+?)$/) {      
                my $action = $array[$i];
                @actionArr=split(/\s+/,$action);
                $action = actionArr[0]; 
                $QUANTITY =actionArr[1]; 

            }
```

Comment: What is `@array`? What is `@F`? How are those variables populated?

Answer (score 0):

Your question really isn't very clear. But, perhaps, something like this:

```
my $action_seen;
while (<$input_fh>) {
  if (/ACTION/) {
    $action_seen = 1;
    next;/
  }

  if ($action_seen) {
    $action_seen = 0;.
    my @data = split;
    # Do whatever you need to do with the data
  }
}
```